# jQuery.attr('src') replace not working in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Strange issue. This code is working perfectly in Chrome / IE. However it does not work in FF 3.6 for some reason. Console shows no JS errors.

It is supposed to look for all images with a specific src attribute and on hover replace the src (I am aware of other approaches like css hover etc, there is a reason why I use this technique - it's not simply rollovers, it's animated video thumbs).

```
$("img[src*='libraries/phpthumb/phpThumbYT.php']").each(function(){
var t=$(this);
var src1= t.attr('src'); // initial src
var old_src = src1.substring(src1.lastIndexOf('media/'), src1.lenght);; // extract old source attr    
var media_id = old_src.substring(6,8); // extract media ID (directory name)
if ( old_src.indexOf("animation=1") != -1 )
{
    t.hover(function(){
        // on hover
        $(this).attr('src', 'libraries/phpthumb/phpThumbYT.php?w=131&h=92&far=C&iar=1&sfn=3&zc=C&f=gif&src=http://domain.name/media/'+media_id+'/preview.gif');  
    }, function(){
       // on rollout
        $(this).attr('src', src1);
    });
}
});
```

I suspect that there might be a problem with the selector maybe? Any ideas?

Comment: `lenght` is generally **not** a property of a `String`.

Comment: Well, I am not an expert at JS, but http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp says it is. However, it's working in Chrome / IE so I don't think that this might be the reason for the FF behaviour?

Comment: typo on ln 4 removed, no effect :(

Comment: If you're using jQuery version 1.6 or later, you should be using `.prop()` and not `.attr()`.

Comment: jQuery version is 1.6.4, unfortunately, changing to `.prop()` did not improve the FF issue (Chrome / IE still working).

Comment: please share one or two urls to images

Comment: I am deply sorry Diode, but I can't do that as the project is only available on local server. However, I have investigated deeper into it. `alert(media_id);` on line 6 shows that the whole extraction process gets messed up in FF for some reason... Chrome/IE show correct ID's, FF is shifted approx 6 chars right in the string...

Comment: Not to access. Just to know the complete url pattern.

Comment: Basically all the image URLs look like this:

`libraries/phpthumb/phpThumbYT.php?w=131&h=92&far=C&iar=1&sfn=3&zc=C&f=gif&src=http://domain.name/media/53/preview.gif`

What changes is the last part and some of the arguments. Static previews end with `preview.jpg&animation=1` where the argument animation is used to distinguish between thumbnails that have an animated preview and those who don't (animation=0).

Comment: definitely, there is an error in this `var old_src = src1.substring(src1.lastIndexOf('media/'), src1.lenght);` - this yelds different values in chrome/ie vs. FF for some reason I don't understand. never thought that there might be a cross-browser issue in this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

The problem was that `src1.lenght` yelded a `'undefined'` value. Although proposed by Alex as the source of the problem, documentation on [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) showed length as a valid property of string.

However, the problem itself was apparently caused by a different handling of the `'undefined'` value in `src1.substring(src1.lastIndexOf('media/'), src1.lenght);`. [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) and IE took the `'undefined'` value simply as not present, therefor the string was parsed till the end. However in [FF](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/) the substring function failed completely returning the whole string.

After isolating this problem I modified the script using sub-string with one argument only, as I actually wanted it to parse until the end, so the second parameter was not needed at all.

Beneath is the final code that works in Chrome + IE + FF.

```
$("img[src*='libraries/phpthumb/phpThumbYT.php']").each(function(){
var t=$(this);
var src1= t.attr('src'); // initial src
var old_src = src1.substring(src1.lastIndexOf('media/')); // extract old source attr    
var media_id = old_src.substring(6,8); // extract media ID (directory name)
media_id = media_id.replace('/',''); // trim '/' from the end of media_id in case the ID is < 10
if ( old_src.indexOf("animation=1") != -1 )
{
    t.hover(function(){
        // on hover
        $(this).attr('src', 'libraries/phpthumb/phpThumbYT.php?w=131&h=92&far=C&iar=1&sfn=3&zc=C&f=gif&src=http://slovoprekazdeho.sk/media/'+media_id+'/preview.gif');  
    }, function(){
       // on rollout
        $(this).attr('src', src1);
    });
}
});
```