# Active button being highlighted for website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

```
<!-- start menu area -->
<div id="menu" class="editable">
<div id="button1" class="repeatable"><a href="/section1.php">Section 1</a></div>
<div id="button2" class="repeatable"><a href="/section2.php">Section 2</a></div>
<div id="button3" class="repeatable"><a href="/section3.php">Section 3</a></div>
</div>
<!-- end menu area -->
```

I don't want to give every single button on each page it's own class. I want to use jQuery, PHP, JavaScript or whatever it takes to get it working without having to go through every single button and give it it's own class.

Also, please note I'm not using navigation bars here, I'm using only divs. Every solution I find uses navigation bars and I can't get them to work when using only divs and hyperlinks.

I want to hightlight the button, or colour it etc.. which matches the current active page.

Comment: Why is your list of links marked up with divs instead of list marku? And did you have a question?

Comment: yes, did you have a question?

Comment: yes sorry, I want to highlight the active button which correlates to the page the user is using.

I didn't do the buttons and have no control over the way they are being written unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu div.repeatable a').each(function(){
        if(document.URL.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) !== -1){
            $(this).addClass('selected');               
        }
    });
});
```

Add `.selected` to your CSS and style it as needed.

This will loop through the menu items and compare the url in the `href` attribute to the current active page url.

You can also use the `divs` inside `#menu` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu div.repeatable').each(function(){
        if(document.URL.indexOf($(this).find('a').attr('href')) !== -1){
            $(this).addClass('selected');               
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution. Sadly I cannot get it to work but I'm not sure why. I've put the script in the <head>. Added the .selected class to my css but it still doesn't work. Also tried #menu .selected...still nothing!!

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your page above this script? Could you possible add the full page HTML so I can check. That code should work just fine.

Comment: thanks for the edit, that seems cool. I can add the full page html, where would be best to do so? also I've searched for including jquery but can't find the correct line. Any chance you know it? Is it a jquery engine that I need to add to make my website work with jquery?

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>

found it :)

Comment: Added that in and still doesn't work. How can i show you my full html code without clogging this page up?

Comment: I've added `div.repeatable` to the selector, that should work. Also, add the .selected to the end of your CSS file if possible. I see that there is some other menu specific CSS in there too

Comment: Tried both the scripts you have above and also moved .selected to the bottom and still doesn't work. Any other ideas? :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="menu" class="editable">
<?php
$i = 0;

while($i < 10)
{
echo '<div id="button'.$i.'" class="repeatable"><a href="/section'.$i.'.php">Section '.$i.'</a></div>';
$i++;
}
?>
</div>
```

Read up on [loops](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp)

Comment: so add that in just below my opening div for my menu?

Comment: It's a loop that'll create 10 buttons with their own ids and sections

Comment: The main reason why the buttons are written in such a way was because we have a CMS where users can duplicate these buttons and make their own. I don't want to change the way these buttons are written I just want to highlight them when someone is on the page for that button without giving each button their own class. This would save editors on the CMS from giving each button a class (working with the elderly so solution has to be simple for them).

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery selectors and .each function. I have done something similar here [jQuery.attr('src') replace not working in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028817/jquery-attrsrc-replace-not-working-in-ff/9034600#9034600).

You could use a similar script to search for every , check the href value and if it fits you, do something with the div... Like adding a style attribute inline, like `style="color: #FF0000;"` to make the text red or whatever you want/need.